# Unable to create Spring boot starter project in STS

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Spring boot architecture. I am trying to create a new spring boot application from the scratch. As a first step, I have installed STS in my machine and also I have the jdk-11 installed and configured in the environment variables section.

I am able to create standalone java applications using STS. But when I try to create a spring-starter project, I am not at all finding any such options in STS(image shown below). Please let me know what I am missing here. Below is the screenshot of my STS.

[image: These are the only options available in STS]

Comment: That screenshot looks wrong - there are options missing - [this is what mine looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rWgP.png). Try re-installing the [latest version](https://spring.io/tools). Describe the precise steps you followed. Check the error logs in `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/log` - or go to Help > About > Installation Details > Configuration > View error log. Update your question accordingly.

Comment: @andrewJames Thanks for your inputs. It worked after installing the latest version which you have suggested. Once again thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my STS installation that I figured out by following the steps provide by andrewJames in the comments section. After installing the latest version(4.17), the problem got resolved.